# simple Back navigation with NavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, swift4

I'm new in Swift and I'm getting stuck with a problem.

Actually it's simple. I try to navigate back from a `UITableView`(B) to `UIView`(A) by clicking a tableview cell. B is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. 
If that works, I want to give tableviewCell data back to controller A. 
I try to do this by calling `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);` 
I reach this function call but nothing happen.

I navigate from A to B via a show segue.

I use Swift 4 and xCode 9.

Pleas help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in different ways.

One is create an object for A in B. When moving to B assign self to that object of A.

```
class BController {
    var a: A!
}
```

When pushing A to B

```
bController.a = self
```

Now you have object of A in B. Assign your value to A when going back to A. and use that value ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear.

Comment: Hello Hari, thanks for answering. This solves the "problem" with the data exchange from B to A right? But my problem is that nothing happen when navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true); is called. I can't move back from B to A.  Please help

Comment: I don't know how you are moving from A to B. Are you using navigtionController?.pushviewcontroller to do this? If this is done navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) definitely works. Make sure you have embedded UINavigationController to A.